# What is the keyboard shortcut to paste from the kill menu in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

Using a fresh Ubuntu install of Emacs, what is the keyboard shortcut to paste from the kill menu? Everything else seems to already have a shortcut defined, does this one need a special entry in the .emacs file or does one exist already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the paste-from-kill menu appear with `f10 e P`. If you have a menu bar, that may not work, and you may need to navigate the menu with arrow keys after you press `f10`. In either case you can also type `` M-\` e P ``.

Another approach is to use the `yank-pop` command, bound to `M-y`. Immediately after you've done a paste, press `M-y` to get replace what you just pasted by the previous kill, and go on pressing `M-y` until you get the text you wanted. If you've gone too far, go backwards with `M-- M-y`. More generally, the prefix argument to `M-y` tells it how many steps to back in the kill ring.

You can directly give a prefix argument to the paste command; for example `C-u 3 C-y` is equivalent to `C-y M-y M-y`.

Answer (score 1):

Also this maybe more helpful.

> If you're using a Debian or Ubuntu Linux distribution, you can install the emacs-goodies-el package, which contains a browse-kill-ring feature (bound to M-y by default).

[Stack Overflow - How do I list all yanks in emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592734/how-do-i-list-all-yanks-in-emacs)